# USB Connection Not Working After Recent AT&T Update on Galaxy S3

Tags: samsung-galaxy-s-3, usb

I found I failed to transfer pics in galaxy to my computer using USB connection after my recent AT&T update. I chose settings->network->more network. And there is an option to tethering via USB and it did prompt with a connecting sound. However, my Samsung device displays as unrecognized device and there is no extra drive popping in my computer. Does any one may know the solution to this?

Answer (score 0):

USB tethering is for sharing the phone's internet connection with the PC. You need to turn this **off**. When you connect the USB cable, tap the USB notification in the notification drawer, and select **Media device (MTP)**.

Comment: Dan, for some reason, I no longer see that notification after I made recent update installation. I knew before I can choose MTP option.